# QGIS + PostgreSQL + row-level-security + SET ROLE in multi-user environment

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Is it possible to execute SET ROLE from within QGIS?

What I want to achieve is to create individual roles for users, that should have access to the same part of data within tables, via existing RLS policies which use CURRENT_USER against a specific table column values. Then use SESSION_USER to audit the tables so that we can keep track of who exactly made some changes.

I can execute it from within DB Manager but it seems to only apply there. I need an easy for a user way to execute it so that it applies for QGIS-browser (so that a user can actually see the tables that he has access to after SET ROLE).

Unfortunetaly PostgreSQL doesn't have any built-in AFTER LOGON triggers so I can't handle it using only backend. I know that in theory I could hardcode RLS policies so that let's say roles A, B, C, D, E all see one anothers updates and inserts but that would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Sounds like a Group Role? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps-2#how-to-use-group-roles-in-postgresql

Comment: Simply granting a role to a role doesn't satisfy RLS policies, which use CURRENT_USER. If I grant A to B and log in as B, it'll still be CURRENT_USER = B and B won't see rows in the table. That's why I want to be able to log in as B and SET ROLE A. Then CURRENT_USER = A but SESSION_USER = B, RLS policies are satisfied and I can use SESSION_USER to audit changes so that I know who exactly made commits. I want to know if and how I can execute SET ROLE in QGIS (apart from DB manager which only applies to DB manager).

Comment: I might be onto something. I found out about the new QGIS Abstract Connections API and using it I managed to do this:
p = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres')
con = p.connections()['name']
con.executeSql('SET ROLE role')
After executing it and refreshing connections in browser it works OK! However when I add table to list of layers werid things happen. Every other time I hit refresh or move around a map, that SET ROLE is lost and keeps reappearing. How do I correct the code?